# error occurs while compiling C code

Tags: c

Temperature of a city in Fahrenheit degrees is input through the keyboard. Now I need to write a program to convert this temperature into Centigrade degrees.

So here is the Formula:

```
°C = (°F -  32)  x  5/9
```

Sample Input/Output:

```
Enter Temperature of Dhaka in Fahreinheit: 98.6
Temperature of Dhaka in Centigrade 37.0 C
Now, i have tried with this, but not works.
```

Code:

```
# include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    float C;
    printf("Pleas Enter Your Fahreinheit Value to see in centrigate=");
    scanf("%d",&C);

    printf(C);

    float output;
    output=(C-32)*(5/9);

    printf("The centrigate Value is = %.2lf\n\n" ,output);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: If you get an error message, please always post that exact error message.

Comment: There are no centigrade degrees. There is only the Celcius scale.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not very precise as an error description, either.

Comment: where did you get `void main()` from. If this is from a book or course work, consider looking somewhere else.

Comment: Google Celsius to Fahrenheit converters. This question has been asked million times before by million other beginner programmers, who all made the same beginner bug as you have in your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
void main()
{
  float far;
  printf("Pleas Enter Your Fahreinheit Value to see in centrigate=");
  scanf("%f",&far);

 // printf(C);

 float cel;
 cel =(far-32)*(5.0/9.0);

 printf("The centrigate Value is = %.2lf\n\n" ,cel);
}
```

1. `5/9` is integer division which gives you `0`. You need float. So do `5.0/9.0` to get the decimal part.
2. And I dont know why you did `printf(C);`. That simply wont work. Use

   ```
    printf("c = %f",c);
   ```
3. The format specifier for float is `%f`. `%d` is used for integers.
4. You provide `C` to store `farenheit`. Now, this is not wrong. But may later cause confusion. Try to use meaningful names in your code so that it is readable. The longer the name the better.

Answer (score 3):

Problems:

- The format specifier in [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) should be `%f`, not `%d` which is for `int`:

  ```
  /* scanf() returns number of assignments made.
     Check it to ensure a float was successfully read. */
  if (1 == scanf("%f", &C))
  {
  }
  ```
- The first argument to [`printf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) should be a `const char*`, not a `float`:

  ```
  printf("C=%f\n", C);
  ```

Comment: i found a problem..why result comes with 0.0000000 can u repair this code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should do some changes, see the comments on code:

```
# include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    float C;
    float output; //Better to declare at the beginning of the block

    printf("Pleas Enter Your Fahreinheit Value to see in centrigate=\n");
    scanf("%f",&C);    //Scanf need %f to read float

    printf("%f\n", C); //becareful with the printf, they need format too.

    output=(C-32)*(5.0/9);    //if you put 5/9 is not a float division, and returns int.
                             //you should add 5.0/9.

    printf("The centrigate Value is = %.2lf\n\n" ,output);
}
```

I think thats all.

Answer (score 0):

The line `printf(C);` should be `printf("%f\n", C);`

Answer (score 0):

`printf("%f\n",C)` instead of `printf(C)`
and
`float output` should be at the beggining of the code like `float C`